# Automatically close a popup

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a wordpress website and I created a popup which has a button that links to Calendly popup. So, when I click on the button, it opens calendly popup in the background but doesnt closes the first popup automatically.

Here is the code I have embedded in the plugin---

```
<link href="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
<a href="" onclick="Calendly.initPopupWidget({url: 'https://calendly.com/#'});return false;">
    <form action="onclick="closeSelf()"">
        <input type="submit" value="Schedule a Demo" />
    </form>
</a>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to close the popup after a few seconds automatically?

Comment: So, there's a button "Schedule My Demo" which is linked to Calendly popup, when i click on this button, calendly popup opens in background and the main popup doenst close, I have to manually close it.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular and javascript first declare calandly

```
declare var Calendly: any;
```

Then in your function calling this one to close calendly popup window

```
Calendly.closePopupWidget();
```